# Filter query result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT split_part(full_path, '/', 4)::INT AS account_id,
       split_part(full_path, '/', 6)::INT AS note_id,
       split_part(full_path, '/', 9)::TEXT AS variation,
       st_size,
       segment_index,
       reverse(split_part(reverse(full_path), '/', 1)) as file_name,
       i.st_ino,
       full_path
FROM gorfs.inodes i
JOIN gorfs.inode_segments s
  ON i.st_ino = s.st_ino_target
```

As you can see, it returns me the 4th "word" as account_id.

```
split_part(full_path, '/', 4)::INT AS account_id,
```

I want to filter that, for example:

```
WHERE account_id = 14134
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you not do `WHERE split_part(full_path, '/', 4)::INT = 14134`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer query.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (
  SELECT
    split_part(full_path, '/', 4)::INT AS account_id,
    ...
) AS whatever_label
WHERE account_id::integer = 14134;
```